# Проблемы записи/чтения json файлов на платформе android в Unity

Tags: unity3d-android

третий день пытаюсь настроить запись/чтение для своей игры на платформе android.

Пробовал три варианта(все не работают):

1. Через Application.presistantDataPath
2. Обрабатывал Application.streamingAssets через UnityWebRequest(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) Таким способом получилось только прочесть файл
3. Создавал файлы при первом старте игры и записывал данные туда

json-ы хранятся в папке Assets/StreamingAssets

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Покажите что вы попробовали и конкретно где не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Я банально забыл про разрешение на запись и чтение файлов.

UPD: В Player settings -> Erite Permission лучше ставить External Storage, Internal Storage работает хуже, как бы это парадоксально не звучало